# UrlRewrite.Net not work in Visual 2013 RC

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I have a website build in VS2012, using UrlRewrite.Net to rewrite url and it work good! But it not work when open in VS2013. Why?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you be more specific than "not work"?

Comment: Error: 404, The resource cannot be found. (when i open in vs 2012 it work ok!)

Comment: Did you get it fixed?

Comment: my urlRewrite dll not support net 4.0, so i use asp.net routing. Thanks @fletchsod!